# GetRequiredService returning null

Tags: c#, azure, dependency-injection

I have the following code:

```
services.AddSingleton<IBlobStorageService>(provider =>
            new BlobStorageService(
                provider.GetRequiredService<IConfigurationService>()["ConnectionString"],
                provider.GetRequiredService<IBlobStorageConfiguration>(),
                provider.GetRequiredService<ILogger>()
            ));
```

When I breakpoint inside the constructor of the singleton:

```
public BlobStorageService(string connString, IBlobStorageConfiguration configuration, ILogger logger) : this(
            CloudBlobClientFactory(connString, logger), configuration, logger)
        {
        }
```

I can see that the IBlobStorageConfiguration "configuration" parameter inside the constructor is null.

Isn't GetRequiredService supposed to throw an exception in this case? There are no IBlobStorageConfiguration implementations in the Startup.cs .

Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions v=3.1.5.0

EDIT, whole startup class (trimmed):

```
public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
{
    private const string LocalSettingsFile = "local.settings.json";

    /// <inheritdoc/>
    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
        IConfigurationRoot configurationRoot = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile(LocalSettingsFile, optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
            .Build();

        builder.Services.AddSingleton(configurationRoot);
        builder.Services.AddLogging();

        CustomConfigurationBuilder configBuilder = new CustomConfigurationBuilder();

        IConfigurationService configService = configBuilder.AddDotNetCoreConfiguration(configurationRoot).Build();

        IServiceCollection services = builder.Services;
        services.AddSingleton(provider => configService);
        services.AddSingleton<IBlobStorageService>(provider =>
            new BlobStorageService(
                provider.GetRequiredService<IConfigurationService>()["StorageConnectionString"],
                provider.GetRequiredService<IBlobStorageConfiguration>(),
                provider.GetRequiredService<ILogger>()
            ));
    }
}
```

Config file:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY": "",
    "AzureServicesAuthConnectionString": "RunAs=Developer; DeveloperTool=AzureCli",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "System.Debug": "True"
  }
}
```

Comment: You have not registered service for type `IBlobStorageConfiguration` ?

Comment: Yes, GetRequiredService is supposed to throw an exception in that case, it shouldn't even call the constructor in the first place. You might need to log a bug in the ASP.NET Core GitHub. Can you confirm that you're using the correct `GetRequiredService` extension method? You might be using one from another namespace than the one you want

Comment: What DependencyInjection provider are you using? The microsoft one or a third party one such as StructureMap, etc.
Could you also provide a full code sample of how your startup.cs look like?

Comment: I can confirm that I am using the correct method and that IConfigurationService is available as it's used everywhere across the solution.

I am using the normal DI from MS by inheriting from FunctionsStartup.

Comment: If `configuration` is null it means that your custom `IConfigurationService`'s indexer  returned null. People can't guess what that custom class is doing. Why are you using a custom service instead of `IConfiguration` anyway? You can use multiple configuration sources and providers. You could use just `services.AddSingleton<IBlobStorageService>()` if you used Configuration and a strongly-typed configuration object. The only thing that forces you to use that factory method is the custom service

Comment: `CustomConfigurationBuilder`? Did you try to create your own configuration middleware? You'll have to post its code then. People know how to us,  configure and customize the built-in Configuration middleware and even find the source code on Github. Only you know what your config middleware does

Comment: @GauravMantri the question says `I can see that "configuration" is null.`. The OP isn't using .NET Core's IConfiguration. This is a custom `IConfigurationService` that returns values through an indexer

Comment: @GauravMantri so do I. That's a string, not an interface. That value was provided by the indexer method of the `IConfigurationService`. There's no `IConfigurationService` in .NET Core. For some reason the OP decided they should wrap the Configuration abstraction with their own Configuration abstraction

Comment: Config file included. The IConfigurationService is NOT null and it is used for accessing the local.settings.json, that's all, so it will resolve the key from the config file. So you're saying I don't need to pass Configuration if I used a strongly-typed configuration object, could you give me some example code of that being done? I am just not sure how one would go about doing that.

Comment: The question says "configuration is null", referring to the parameter inside the constructor named "configuration".

Comment: The string returned from `provider.GetRequiredService<IConfigurationService>()["StorageConnectionString"]` is working correctly and is returning the correct value in the constructor. I am talking about the `IBlobStorageConfiguration configuration` parameter in the constructor being null.

Comment: Please review the code for `GetRequiredService`: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/b7f505dcb13f0fd80a33c962446bf13f87a31b33/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions/src/ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.cs#L58. This method does not return `null`.